# Nagios interval_length and check_interval

Tags: nagios

I am getting a little confused with Nagios timers.

Whilst testing, I set a failure that was not picked up for around 5 minutes. I am not much more than pings and http checks and I really want to step up the timers.

I have seen the main `interval_length` by default is set to 60 and I set this to 10, along with changing `check_interval` on a single object to 1 (nothing on inheritance).

What I don't get is that clicking on the host itself seems to show that the difference between `Last Check Time` and `Next Scheduled Active Check` is 30 seconds, along with the `Last Update` happening once every 10 seconds.

I am just not sure what is going on here!

Can anyone recommend the correct way for going about doing a ping every 10 seconds or any other way to achieve much lower times between checks?

---

Edit - found `check_result_reaper_frequency=10` in the nagios.cfg file and now understand why the last update is every 10 seconds... Still puzzled about the delay between actual checks, so, leaving question open.

Comment: Those are very aggressive check times.  is it possible that with those definitions your server cannot keep up with the schedule demands?  Take a look at the Scheduling Queue (near bottom of menu)  to see if it is falling behind.

Comment: @Uslackr - I am not really sure how to interpret that page... it looks alright as far as I can tell... The server certainly has the horsepower to do more than it is, I really want to know if I have used the correct settings or if I should be doing something else?

Comment: How about the `retry_interval`?

Answer (score -2):

You  Edit file `nagios.cfg`

sudo vim /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg

service_check_timeout=10 #60

**host_check_timeout=5 #30**

Because Check HOST ALERT based on timeout, but Check Host Alert is Correct, and Check Service Alert not correct. :D